# What is the equivalent of "android:windowSoftInputMode" for a web site?

Tags: android, input, web

I'm building a web site app that will be used from Android devices. At the moment, the browser squashes the page when the soft keyboard appears. I rather want it to scroll the page up.

I've read that the property [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)  in `AndroidManifest.xml` can be used for Android apps, but I'm looking for an equivalent for a web site.

Comment: Where u able to solve this issue? Please let me immediately.

Comment: I suggest to you read about android:windowSoftInputMode in this link :
[developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Comment: I suggest you create an app with a webview such that bothWindowSoftInputMode as well as your website can exist side-by-side

Comment: Anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 6):

You can reposition the browser when the user focuses on this input

```
<input name="whatever" id="id" onfocus="window.location.href='#id'; return true;"/>
```

Comment: I assume the soft keyboard appears when the user touches this input. I suppose you'll be able to adapt for a different behaviour if needed.

Comment: I have not managed to try this yet as the tablet has been taken out of the office. If anyone else could see if this works I would appreciate it

Comment: @Parallel2ne I've tested this with AOSP stock browser and Opera mobile. I see no reason it shouldn't work, provided javascript is enabled